# wyse 3360 dhcp - rdp not working

Tags: dhcp, rdp

Have an older wyse 3360 winterm thin client device, firmware 3.5.1 sp2, build 441.22.

We have several of these units that work fine when a manual ip address is assigned. But when dhcp is used on the thin client, they won't connect to a windows 2003 rdp server. The windows 2003 rdp server in question is used in production by many clients, pc based and thin clients, so I wouldn't suspect the server.

This is on a local lan, 10/100 ethernet, a cisco 3550 switch connects the wyse to the dhcp server and the rdp terminal server. The dhcp server is w2k3 sp2, 32 bit. Rdp server is win 2k3 server, sp2 64 bit.

When dhcp is used on the wyse, they will connect to our unix server with a terminal emulation session, so we know that dhcp works as far as network connectivity goes. It's just the rdp session won't work. Very odd. Is their a dhcp option that the wyse needs to be receiving in order for rdp to work?

ip address being assigned to the wyse via dhcp is 10.1.90.31 , 255.255.0.0.  When this address (or a similiar one like 10.1.90.20 / 255.255.0.0) is assigned manually rdp sessions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Since thin client was using DNS (and not wins), have to specify the fqdn for the rdp server. Not exactly intuitive on some of these older devices, they don't have ability to make a lan broadcast to discover the name, as most modern win os's would.